# Do virtual particles bend spacetime?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, virtual-particles

I am new to QFT and has been studying it for about an year. I had gone through few of the Standard QFT textbooks, but couldn't get any answer regarding my query.

Comment: The virtual particles in qft are not physical, this question doesn't really have a answer.

Comment: also bear in mind that virtual particles are mathematical functions in quantum mechanics, and general relativity has not been definitively quantized yet.

Comment: "Virtual particles" is perhaps the most misleading term in all of physics. It refers to a mathematical term in the equation and nothing else. That term looks and behaves (mathematically!) a lot like a particle, which partly justifies terminology, but looking at how many people take it too seriously, I think we would be better off without ever inventing such a term in the first place.

Comment: @Prof. Legolasov Isn't your parting indictment of the term too harsh? It is a perfectly fine codeword for something off-shell. It is the abusive adoption of it by clueless science writers and the weaving of a fantasy story around it that is at fault. Working physicists use it all the time without a problem, which explains its survival. The question above is already sick at the higher, unstated, level: the OP apparently visualizes *real* particles bending spacetime in a meaningful way?!

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have no doubt it is a fine codeword for you, for example. Since I know you understand the actual math behind it, I'm sure you can use that codeword efficiently and avoid confusion. I don't mind using any term as long as people who use it understand what they're talking about. My point is that virtual particles have contributed to so much confusion among young / inexperienced passionate learners (as is evident from simply looking at posts on this very site with the "virtual particles" tag) that I haven't seen any other term contribute to

Comment: Probably in agreement... up there with wave/particle  or the uncertainty principle....